# Expressions in path filter

Tags: github-actions

I'm trying to write a workflow that can accept variables in path filtering. The idea is that many Actions will reference different subdirectories in the same parent directory in their path filters. Therefore, I'd like the parent directory to be stored in a variable so that if the location ever changes, I can simply update that variable without having to touch the actions at all.

Example:

```yaml
path: format('{0}/{1}', env.Parent, 'actions_subdirectory')
```

However, I have tried many variations of the above but I cannot get my action to properly scan the referenced directory for changes.

The variations:

```yaml
path: format('{0}/{1}', env.Parent, 'actions_subdirectory')

path: format('{0}/{1}', env.Parent, 'actions_subdirectory/*')

path: format('{0}/{1}', env.Parent, 'actions_subdirectory/**')
```

These variations do not result in the directory being scanned, and the action is not executed even if the directory has changes

Adding curly braces, such as:

```yaml
path: ${{ format('{0}/{1}', env.Parent, 'actions_subdirectory') }}
```

Gives me the error: `A template expression is not allowed in this context` and does not work either. I'm not that familiar with contexts at this point so I'm not really sure what that means beyond that I just shouldn't use that formatting.

Comment: As it tells you when you use `${{ ... }}`, the path can't be an expression. So you're literally checking for paths matching `format...`, no evaluation or interpolation happens.

Comment: Where exactly are you trying to do this? In `on.<pull_request|push>`? If so, it should be `paths` to begin with.

Comment: Also, it feels like [configuration variables](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/variables#defining-configuration-variables-for-multiple-workflows) should work for this, but it doesn't look like they do ("Unrecognized named-value: 'vars'.").